Setting window to WS_POPUP style in winapi doesn't work correctly
I have a problem when using this:
SetWindowLongPtr(window_handle, GWL_STYLE, WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_CLIPCHILDREN | WS_POPUP)

If I create a window with these styles, it will display as a window with no borders and caption, as I want:

But, if I set these styles via SetWindowLongPtr(), the window will look like this instead:

I can't move it, or click on it, it just focuses the window underneath my window.
It also disappears from the Taskbar, and the Alt+Tab menu, so I can only close it via Task Manager.
If I use SetWindowLongPtr() and SetWindowPos() multiple times, the window starts behaving the way I want it to and hides the borders, but this doesn't seem like the right way to do it because I need to do it multiple times.
Does anyone have any tips, or know in which direction to look for a solution to this problem?
Maybe I need to add some catches to the window process, or add something in the window creation process?

When you change window styles that affect the frame you need to call SetWindowPos() with the SWP_FRAMECHANGED flag.

@JonathanPotter that should be posted as an answer.

According to Jonathan Potter's suggestion:

When you change window styles that affect the frame you need to call SetWindowPos() with the SWP_FRAMECHANGED flag.

